# Extract content between same strings via Regex

Tags: html, regex

I would like to capture everything between 2 same strings.

```
String1: two
String2: two
```

EXAMPLE:

```
two strings two 123 twoIKStwo .[]?>-=two&1`ddddtwo()dsaltwo
```

RESULT:

```
 strings , 
 123 ,
IKS,
 .[]?>-=,
&1`dddd,
()dsal
```

**including line-break and any invisible characters.*

I have tried several Regexes but I've failed miserably. I would like to capture one group results if possible, and purely in Regex syntax. I want to capture everything inside  I have searched across the web, but it seems nobody needs to accomplish this or second option is that it is extremely easy to do it, so nobody is asking for that.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: Why are you using regex? JavaScript's `split` lets you say what that string is and then literally does what you're asking about doing here. `input.split('two')` and we're done.

Comment: If this is for "unknown input", though, please explain that in your post, because what do you imagine should happen for `"this is a test: this is not a test is it?"`, where _no amount of splitting_ is going to be "correct" without first defining what correct is for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex:

```
([A-Za-z]+)(.*?)(?=\1)
```

And then capture group 2.

Output:

```
Match 1
Group 2.    3-12    ` strings `
Match 2
Group 2.    15-20   ` 123 `
Match 3
Group 2.    23-26   `IKS`
Match 4
Group 2.    29-37   ` .[]?>-=`
Match 5
Group 2.    40-47   `&1`dddd`
Match 6
Group 2.    50-56   `()dsal`
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/wJ7hW5/1

Comment: There is no reason for a regex here at all, though, given the explanation of what they're trying to achieve. (and given that they don't say what should happen on mixed pair input, suggesting that's not a concern)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes agreed. But just shared what OP asked for :)